# Jar dependencies for Jersey+RESTful web services+JSON with JDK 1.5

Tags: java, json, rest, jar

[image]

[image]

Would anyone suggest which jars to use for jersey+restful webservices+json where I can convert custom object let say, employee to json and vice versa.
**Please note I have to use JDK 1.5.**
I am using jars as

```
asm-3.1.jar, 
cglib-nodep-2.1.3.jar, 
javax.ws.rs.jar, 
jersey-core-1.0.3.jar, 
jersey-json-1.0.3.jar, 
jersey-server-1.0.3.jar.
```

> SEVERE: A message body writer for Java type, class com.XXX.rest.Track, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found
>   Blockquote

I also tried varios options over stackoverflow. Whatever solutions I got in form of jar dependencies were compiled in JDK 1.6 and above causing in Bad version error.
Please help me out in this. your suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: read about `jaxb`, you don't need any additional jar actually.

Comment: jaxb(Java Architecture for XML Binding) mostly used for converting xml to object and vice versa. does it support **JSON**. if yes then from which version which is compatible with JDK5.

Comment: who said??? don't go with the name .. did you even google "jaxb and restful" ??

Comment: yes, I googled with the same. I am getting only xml based restful services example not json, which can convert object to json.

Comment: I'm not sure, which version of Google are you using ... This is first link I get when I google.. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkknj.html

Comment: thanks @Ravi ... Not getting compatible versions of jars with jdk 5.

Comment: I just noticed, you are using JDK5, which is **too old**. We already have JDK9. There is no point of using that old JDK, you should atleast use JDK7.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/jersey-json/jersey-json.jar.zip
Download this jar file.The  jar file contains the following class files or Java source files.
This will surely solve your errors.Try it out.

Comment: I have added links for jars included in my project. would you please refer to the first link added just before my question begins?

Comment: tried the same thing but could not work with jdk 5 to support json. Finally have added gson library and worked for me.